# Error while inserting into DynamoDB local "Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamo-local

I am trying to insert the item into AmazonDB local instance, but, I keep getting this error.

```
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.PutItemRequest.getConditionalOperator
```

Could you please help me progress?

Thanks,

Comment: also add the code...!!!

Comment: Please add full stack trace, SDK version, and indicate whether DynamoDB Local is throwing the exception or your client code is throwing the exception.

Comment: Hey. Did you get the solution of this problem I am also facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Versions of the AWS SDK released on or after to April 24, 2014 support conditional writes ([announcement](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/improved-queries-and-updates-for-dynamodb/)). Please make sure you are using the latest version of DynamoDB Local and the latest version of the AWS SDK.